# Error in javascript file

Tags: javascript

```
function ()
 {
    $('body, .navbar-collapse div[role="search"] button[type="reset"]')
        .on('click keyup', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            if (event.which == 27 && $('.navbar-collapse div[role="search"]')
                .hasClass('active') ||
            $(event.currentTarget).attr('type') == 'reset') {
            closeSearch();
                            }
                            });
                     closeSearch();

               function closeSearch() {
        $('#navbar-searchform, #navbar-reset').addClass('hidden');
        var $form = $('.navbar-collapse div[role="search"].active')
        $form.find('input').val('');

        $form.removeClass('active');
        $('#navbar-search').removeClass('hidden');
    }
        // Show Search if form is not active // event.preventDefault() is important, this prevents the form from submitting

    $(document).on('click',.navbar-collapse div[role="search"]:not(.active)    button[type="submit"]',

        function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this).closest('div[role="search"]'),
                $input = $form.find('input');
            $form.addClass('active');
            $('#navbar-searchform, #navbar-reset')
             .removeClass('hidden'); $input.focus();
             $(this).addClass('hidden');

        });
```

I am trying to figure out what is wrong in this code. This is meant to enable the search form to hide and then only appear once I click on the search button. It worked but it ended up affecting the navbar to the point where if I click anything, the page would not load unless I open it in a new tab.

Comment: `$(document).on('click',.navbar-collapse div[role="search"]:not(.active)    button[type="submit"]',` That line should be bringing up an error message in your developer console.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the developer console and you should see the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` It is because you missed the opening `'` on your selector string.

```
$(document).on('click',.navbar-collapse div[role="search"]:not(.active)    button[type="submit"]',
                      ^^^
```

Comment: Why not just close as typo? The problem is answered in comment

Comment: ANd I am the one that wrote the comment... And I closed it as a typo .... and I answered it.... and now I commented. ;)